# UIColor getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: returns NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, uicolor, ios11

I am using the following function to "change" the saturation, brightness and alpha of a `UIColor`:

```
//UIColor *color = [self color:[UIColor redColor] saturation:0.5 brightness:0.5 alpha:0.5];

- (UIColor *)color:(UIColor *)color saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    CGFloat h, s, b, a;
    [color getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:h saturation:(s * saturation) brightness:(b * brightness) alpha:(a * alpha)];
}
```

Prior to iOS 11 (GM) this was working perfectly fine. However, now `[UIColor getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:]` returns `NO` and the hsba values aren't getting changed.

Comment in `UIColor.h` says:

> If the receiver is of a compatible color space, any non-NULL
>   parameters are populated and 'YES' is returned. Otherwise, the
>   parameters are left unchanged and 'NO' is returned.

What does "compatible color space" mean here? Do I have to convert color spaces? How do I accomplish that?
All the colors in my .xcassets are in sRGB.

---

**EDIT:** Kind of a fix is to use the following way to get the HSBA values:

```
CGFloat rTemp, gTemp, bTemp, aTemp;
[color getRed:&rTemp green:&gTemp blue:&bTemp alpha:&aTemp];
CGFloat h, s, b, a;
[[UIColor colorWithRed:rTemp green:gTemp blue:bTemp alpha:aTemp] getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];
```

Comment: A quick test shows that the code works if the passed in `UIColor` is created via code instead of from an asset.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I noticed that too. But why doesn‘t this work with sRGB?

Comment: I was going to explain what's going on here and how best to proceed but it seems you've already accepted an answer. I suggest letting your question simmer a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that the `UIColor getHue:saturation:brightness:` method doesn't work if the color's color space is sRGB but it does work if the color's color space is Extended sRGB.

So the solution is to update the selected Color Space for each of your colors in your color set asset.

This can be demonstrated in a Swift Playground as follows. This creates a color using the sRGB color space.

```
if let cs = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) {
    if let cc = CGColor(colorSpace: cs, components: [0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0]) {
        let color = UIColor(cgColor: cc)
        print(color)
        var h: CGFloat = 0
        var s: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        if color.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: nil) {
            print(h, s, b)
        } else {
            print("Failed with color space \(cs)")
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

> kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0.5 0.7 0.3 1
>   Failed with color space  (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)

Updating the above code to use the `CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB` color space gives the following results:

> UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.5 0.7 0.3 1
>   0.25 0.571428571428571 0.7

Comment: It feels like changing the color space of the color assets isn't the best solution, since I want the function to work ideally with all color spaces and I also use the color assets in interface builder and want them to be displayed correctly.

Comment: If you want your method to work with any colorspace then you will have to write code to convert from unsupported colorspaces to a supported colorspace. But since you have control over the colorspace, why bother? Is there a problem if you convert the colors to Extended sRGB? Does IB have a problem with Extended sRGB colors?

Comment: No, it does work. I'm not really familiar with different color spaces but I try to have the same color space throughout my programs (design program > export > Xcode) to avoid any issues. But since Extended sRGB seems to be very similar to sRGB (?) I figure there shouldn't be any problems, am I right?

Comment: Clearly there are problems since sRGB doesn't work with the getHue... method but Extended sRGB does. I have no idea if one or the other will cause issues with IB. But your tests indicate that Extended sRGB works so go with that throughout your app.